# How to expose a net.tcp wcf service over the network?

Tags: wcf, networking, configuration

I have a problem with my client-server application, I would be very gratefull if you can help me. 
I have a self-hosted server, and the problem is that in my local machine the service works just fine, in the development enviroment. Im trying to do the same but throughout the network. I have this configured on net.tcp://localhost:8990/ .., but i realized via netstat that the service was on 127.0.0.1 that is my localhost,  so i've tried net.tcp://192.168.0.12:8990/ , that is my ip over the network, but still can see it, and the client cant connect either.
I tried register it as a windows service, but i cant get the service exposed.
I have disabled all the firewalls, so i have no idea what else to try. 
Thanks for your help!
Alejandra

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I hadn't run the netsh command to port reservation. I've tried before, but the command gave me one error on parameters, It has to do with the fact the example was user=\Everyone, and in my local configuration it has to be user=\Todos. After doing this, I can se the program exposed on that port.
Thanks